# How do I migrate Parse Cloud Code to Firebase?

Tags: parse-platform, firebase

Today (5/19/2016) I received an email from Firebase.com announcing its largest expansion.

I want to know if **now** I can deploy custom code to Firebase.com? Doing that in Parse.com was very easy, for example:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
    response.success("Hello world!");
});
```

How can I do the same with firebase.com?

Comment: I think Firebase still doesnt have something like Cloud code as Parse. Maybe you can run it in google cloud platform though...

Comment: I am wondering the same question

Comment: You can just migrate your Parse Server to Google Cloud, then it's practically sitting next to the same physical servers as Firebase

Answer (score 1):

No. Firebase does not provide server side logic. You need to choose your own like Heroku, Google Cloud Platform, etc.